Enforce kubeconfig token expiry for Entra ID enabled cluster AKS cluster
Recently I enabled Entra ID login for AKS cluster,
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "this" {
...
  azure_active_directory_role_based_access_control {
    admin_group_object_ids = var.entraid_group_ids_cluster_admin
    azure_rbac_enabled     = false
    tenant_id              = var.tenant_id
  }
...

and installed kubelogin
az account set --subscription [REDACTED]
az aks get-credentials --resource-group [RG] --name [NAME]
kubelogin convert-kubeconfig -l azurecli

For the first time kubectl access after I enabled Entra ID, it asked for OTP and I can also see token in below path
$ ls  ~/.kube/cache/kubelogin/AzurePublicCloud-6dae42f8-4368-4678-94ff-3960e28e3630-80faf920-1908-4b52-b5ef-a8e7bedfc67a-97428d91-daa2-4245-a358-87ce5cc734f6.json
/Users/user.name/.kube/cache/kubelogin/AzurePublicCloud-6dae42f8-4368-4678-94ff-3960e28e3630-80faf920-1908-4b52-b5ef-a8e7bedfc67a-97428d91-daa2-4245-a358-87ce5cc734f6.json

I have been using kubectl access for a week, I see it never asked for OTP again (I think the token expiry time is 24 hours!?). If I look inside the cache token
$ cat ~/.kube/cache/kubelogin/AzurePublicCloud-6dae42f8-4368-4678-94ff-3960e28e3630-80faf920-1908-4b52-b5ef-a8e7bedfc67a-97428d91-daa2-4245-a358-87ce5cc734f6.json
{"access_token":"[REDACTED]","expires_in":4932,"expires_on":1727278105,"not_before":1727272872,"resource":"6dae42e8-4360-4679-94ef-3660e28f3630","token_type":"Bearer"}

The epoch time for "expires_on":1727278105 is Wednesday, 25 September 2024 15:28:25, the token is expired and isn't it should ask for OTP login again?
How to enforce expiry for kubeconfig token in this case? For example, after 24 hours, it should aks for OTP when I try to use kubectl

The token expiration time for Microsoft Entra ID-enabled AKS clusters is managed by Entra ID and cannot be modified. The default expiration time for Entra ID tokens is 24 hours. To enforce token expiry for kubeconfig, you can use the kubelogin command kubelogin remove-tokens to remove the cached tokens.

The expiration time for the kubectl token is determined by the Microsoft Entra ID configuration and cannot be modified. The token is cached and will only prompt for OTP again after it has expired or the K8s config file is re-created. The token lifetime is designed such that it cannot be less than 60 minutes. If you want to enforce a shorter token lifetime, you can use Privileged Identity Management to control access to your AKS cluster. By default, the Entra ID token has a 24-hour expiration time. You can use the kubelogin command kubelogin remove-tokens to remove the cached tokens. This will force to request a new token from Entra ID the next time it is used.
You can automate this using a cron job / script
crontab -e
0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/kubelogin remove-tokens

This will run the remove-tokens command daily at midnight.
Checkout these MS docs for reference

Access cluster with Microsoft Entra ID
Use PIM to control access to your AKS clusters

Also please see these similar threads posted on MS QnA forum-

Change device authorization token expiration time in AKS AD RBAC authentication - Microsoft Q&A

Default credentials expiration time for Azure Kubernetes RBAC - Microsoft Q&A


